# Building List from Variables in Python

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have these variables:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = 'yay'
c = 'cool'
```

I want to build a list `d` which contains:

`['yay', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'cool']`

I'd tried `d = [b, a, c]` but the result isn't what I wanted, it became:

`['yay', ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'cool']`

please if someone could help me.

Answer (score 7):

You could do:

```
d = [b, *a, c]
```

To unpack the values of the list into the new list

Answer (score 1):

They way you are trying to add elements is adding a separate list try to use extend method of list which extends the previous list from the provided one

```
myList = []
myList.append(b)
myList.extend(a) #this is what you are looking for . 
myList.append(c)
print(myList) # ['yay', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'cool']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make the lists out of them and use addition operator `+` among the lists.

```py
[b] + a + [c]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
['yay', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'cool']
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.extend` method will extend the list.

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = 'yay'
c = 'cool'
d=[]
d.extend(a)
d.append(b)
d.append(c)
```

You can also do

```
a+[b]+[c]
```